# What are some better ways to print the following section?

Tags: java

What are some better ways to print the following section? I think it will look better in a table format of some type with a heading. I want to adjust them to fixed lenghts, I think. Here is the code snippet I want to format to look better. The print elements are elements in a sql database.

```
 System.out.println("\nAll records in your table:");
 System.out.println("ID#     Name           GPA  Status Mentor Level Thesis Advisor  Company"); //table heading...
 while (rs.next()) {
     String output = " ";
     output += rs.getString("studentID") + "    "
         + rs.getString("firstName") + " "
         + rs.getString("lastName") + " "
         + rs.getString("gpa") + "    "
         + rs.getString("status") + "   "
         + rs.getString("mentor") + " "
         + rs.getString("level") + " "
         + rs.getString("thesisTitle") + " "
         + rs.getString("thesisAdvisor") + " "
         + rs.getString("company") + "\n";
     System.out.printf("%s", output);
 }
```

Comment: Besides not being a super question, you've provided absolutely nothing in the way of requirements. Look better how? In what context/medium? If you just want to justify, use `printf`.

Comment: A table like displayed in the [mysql client](http://www.tutorialsweb.com/sql/images/mysql.2.gif)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

|You can|
|Do something|
|like this|

|studentname|
|firstname|
|middlename|
|.......|

Answer (score 0):

"I want to adjust them to fixed lengths": 

is that why your concatenating whitespaces in different lengths ? 

You can try to concatenate "\t\t" instead. 

In case it's HTML, using **[HTML Table](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html)** will take care of it for you.